# How can I convert a BitString to a ctypes Byte Array?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, bitstring

I've just started out with BitString and ctypes, and I have part of a binary file stored in `startdata`, a [`BitArray`](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/bitarray.html) class.

```
> print(startdata)
0x0000000109f0000000010605ffff
```

Now, I have to pass this data as-is to a C function that takes an `unsigned char *` as argument, so I'm first trying to do something like this:

```
buf = (c_ubyte * len(startdata))()
```

to finally do this:

```
buf_ptr = cast(pointer(buf), POINTER(c_ubyte))
```

This works, but how do I assign the byte data from `startdata` to that array / buffer I just created?

This doesn't work:

```
> buf = (c_ubyte * len(startdata))(*startdata.bytes)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution (note that I'm using python 3):

```
import ctypes

def bitarray_to_ctypes_byte_buffer(data):
    """Convert a BitArray instance to a ctypes array instance"""
    ba = bytearray(data.bytes)
    ba_len = len(ba)
    buffer = (ctypes.c_uint8 * ba_len).from_buffer(ba)
    return buffer
```

(Note: the same apply for converting a `bytes` instance to a ctypes byte array, just remove `.bytes` in `data.bytes`).

You can then pass the buffer to your C function by using [`byref`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference):

```
byref(buffer)
```

Comment: When I do that, it says: `ValueError: Buffer size too small (786 instead of at least 6288 bytes)`. In my case, `len(startdata)` is 6288. Do you know why that happens? I'm using `bytearray(startdata.bytes)` with the [`bytes`](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/constbitarray.html#bitstring.Bits.bytes) function.

Comment: @slhck: the correct line should be something like: `buffer = (ctypes.c_uint8 * len(startdata.bytes)).from_buffer(bytearray(startdata.bytes))`, given `startdata` in this context is an instance of `BitArray` . Make sure you get the length of the correct object.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Maybe if you could edit those parts in your answer so that they work with the `BitArray` instance? :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know why the OP needs a `c_ubyte` array instead of a `c_char` array. For the latter you can use `buffer = create_string_buffer(data.bytes)`. This appends a terminating null byte, which the library may expect. Otherwise use `b = data.bytes;` `buffer = (c_ubyte * len(b)).from_buffer_copy(b)`.

Comment: I forgot to add that passing an `Array` using `byref` is unnecessary. C arrays are always passed by reference. You do need `byref` in order to pass a reference otherwise, i.e. to a simple type (`_SimpleCData`), a pointer (`_Pointer` or `_CFuncPtr`), a `Structure`, or a `Union`. So if code needs to treat all ctypes buffers generically, then using `byref` on an array is fine.

Comment: @eryksun I did not see your comment, would've been good to @-ping me :) The function signature I need to work with takes `unsigned char * `, and it's been many many years since I've last used C++. Ctypes documentation says [unsigned char corresponds to `c_ubyte`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types). That's why I took that.

Comment: @slhck, that's an array of bytes all the same. Working with `c_char` arrays and `c_char_p` may be more convenient. For example, a `c_char` array has a `value` attribute that makes it easy to assign a (byte) string, and it does automatic conversion to a (byte) string when used as a result type or accessed as a struct field.